# Landscape screenshot for appstore is shown in portrait mode on Device (iPhone) AppStore application

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect, screenshot

We have uploaded screenshots in both portrait and landscape for iPhone 6.5 while submitting the application to AppStore.. and when we are browsing the application on AppStore on Device (iPhone), we observed that landscape screenshot has been rotated to portrait.

is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Apple Support Team, The screenshots should only be in one single orientation, Landscape or Portrait.
If they are uploaded in both orientations, they will be shown only in portrait orientation on the Appstore for iOS Devices.